# having trouble with FullTextSearch

Tags: mysql

I'm new with `MySQL FULLTEXTSEARCH`. Here's what I have tried,

```
SELECT * 
FROM example_myisam
WHERE MATCH(data, data2) AGAINST ('+*ar' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

but it gave me zero result. What I'm looking is to convert this `LIKE` statement in `FULLTEXT`

```
SELECT *
FROM example_myisam 
WHERE data LIKE '%ar' OR
      data2 LIKE '%ar';
```

here's a demo if it helps: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d3fdd/12

Here's also my DDL statement:

```
CREATE TABLE example_myisam
(
    id     INT,
    data   VARCHAR(50),
    data2  VARCHAR(50)
) ENGINE = MYISAM;

ALTER TABLE example_myisam ADD FULLTEXT alltext (data, data2);
```

Comment: Do you have FULLTEXT indexes set up in your table?

Answer (score 1):

You may have to do a combination of `MATCH()...AGAINST()` and `LIKE` to get the results you want. The `*` is used to find words with a prefix. So, it has to be used like `Vict*`.

Comment: is there no other way to search for containing string?

Comment: I honestly think this is your best option. Unless you want to pull all of the results, and sort through them with a regex in your code, which I don't think you want to do.